# Is there a way to mapping values to Object list from YAML

Tags: java, micronaut

​I'm trying to create a list of servers objects from YAML file as I saw on this [post](https://www.fortisfio.com/yaml-file-mapping-values-to-object-list-with-spring-boot/), but with Micronaut.

My YAML file has this config:

```
server:
    -
        name: "Server 1"
        flow: "both"
        environment: "test"
    -
        name: "Server 2"
        flow: "both"
        environment: "production"
```

My POJO is:

```
package dev.renansouza.server;

public class Server {

    private String name;
    private String flow;
    private String environment;

    public Server() {}

    public Server(String name, String flow, String environment) {
        this.name = name;
        this.flow = flow;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFlow() {
        return flow;
    }

    public void setFlow(String flow) {
        this.flow = flow;
    }

    public String getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(String environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Servers -> name: " + name + " flow: " + flow + " environment: " + environment;
    }

}
```

And my service is:

```
package dev.renansouza.server;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.ConfigurationProperties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static dev.renansouza.server.ServerService.PREFIX;

@Singleton
@ConfigurationProperties(PREFIX)
public class ServerService {

    public static final String PREFIX = "server";

    private List<Server> networkRules = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for(Server s : this.getServers()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public List<Server> getServers() {
        return this.networkRules;
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the System.out.println line and started the application as debug, but nothing happens.

Do I need to do any extra configuration?

Comment: `@EachProperty` will help you.  See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.4/guide/index.html#eachProperty.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm trying to do as the documentation. I even try somethings that [mrhaki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/search/label/Micronaut) did in his blog, but I never get any result. If it helps, I created a branch to implement this at [github](https://github.com/renansouza-dev/document-unpack/tree/add-server-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzaproperties.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzaproperties/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: renansouzaproperties
server:
    Server 1:
        flow: both
        environment: test
    Server 2:
        flow: both
        environment: production
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzaproperties/blob/master/src/main/java/renansouzaproperties/Server.java

```
package renansouzaproperties;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.EachProperty;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Parameter;

@EachProperty("server")
public class Server {
    private String name;
    private String flow;
    private String environment;

    public Server(@Parameter String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFlow() {
        return flow;
    }

    public void setFlow(String flow) {
        this.flow = flow;
    }

    public String getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(String environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Servers -> name: " + name + " flow: " + flow + " environment: " + environment;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzaproperties/blob/master/src/main/java/renansouzaproperties/DemoController.java

```
package renansouzaproperties;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;

import java.util.List;

@Controller("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    private List<Server> serverList;

    public DemoController(List<Server> serverList) {
        this.serverList = serverList;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public HttpStatus index() {
        for(Server server: serverList) {
            System.out.println(server);
        }
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
}
```

If you start the app and send a request to http://localhost:8080/demo you will see output that looks like this which indicates that the desired `Server` instances have been created:

```
Servers -> name: server 1 flow: both environment: test
Servers -> name: server 2 flow: both environment: production
```

I realize that your question explicitly asks about a list in the yaml and this example isn't using a list but from other comments and the sample code you posted it doesn't look like you really need a list in the yaml.  If you really do want a list in the yaml there is a way to do that too.  Let me know if that really is what you need.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Jeff,

You save the day again. I thought a list will be the best implementation for my need. Indeed, your solution fits this need that is:

* create a folder for each server;
* create a sub-folder for each flow;

I hope my path to learning micronaut help others in the future.

Best Regards,
Renan Souza